# Does ts-node support '@' style import? If so, how to set it up?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-node

I'm creating a command-line script, using classes from the main express app.

Script resides in the folder:

```
bin/utils/
├── sync-buyers.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

The main express app is in `/app` use uses `import '@/foo/bar/thing`.

This is set up in the `tsconfig.json` of the main app, as follows:

```
"paths": {
        "@/*": ["*"],
        "*": [
            "node_modules/*",
            "app/typings/*"
        ]
    }
},
"include": ["app/**/*", "test/**/*"],
"exclude": ["app/**/*.test.ts", "/__tests__/", "/__mocks__/", "/__snapshots__/", "app/**/__mocks__/"],
"files": ["typings/global.d.ts"]
```

**Script Execution**

I'm testing to see if I can import from the main app, so I created a `sayHello()` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node
/* tslint:disable */

import { sayHello } from '../../app/services/v2/oapp';
sayHello();
```

When I run it:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
../../app/services/v2/oapp.ts(9,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module 
'@/helpers/fetch'.
../../app/services/v2/oapp.ts(10,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 
'@/services/v2/buyer'.
../../app/services/v2/oapp.ts(11,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module 
'@/http/HttpHeader'.
```

*Summary:*

Does ts-node support '@' style of import? If so, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the TypeScript `paths` configuration only applies to TypeScript's type resolution and checking, meaning that it will allow TypeScript to understand those imports for the purposes of type-checking only, but the code it generates won't automatically rewrite those imports to the correct locations.

There's two common approaches for solving this:

1. Update the Node resolver to understand the TypeScript `paths` config.  The generated files will still refer to those paths by their @-name.

   Most commonly, the [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) module is used for this.  You can require that module from the `node` command directly:

   ```
   node -r tsconfig-paths/register main.js
   ```
2. Rewrite the generated files so that the @-names get replaced with the "real" local relative path locations.

   There's a standalone module for this, [`tspath`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath) - you simply run `tspath` after compiling your TypeScript, and it updates the generated files with the correct paths.

   If you're using Webpack, you can also use [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin), which will take care of configuring Webpack's resolver to correctly locate those @-name paths.

   And finally if you're using Babel, you might be interested in [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) which does a similar thing for the Babel toolchain, however the downside here is it doesn't read the `paths` config from `tsconfig.json`, so you essentially have to duplicate your `paths` config in the `alias` config of this plugin.

Personally I'd recommend `tsconfig-paths` if this is a Node script or server that's compiled with `tsc` directly and `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` if this is a frontend Webpack build.